# Global variable doesn't save correctly when set from a Process()

Tags: python, web-applications, global-variables, flask, multiprocessing

In this Flask app, the page calls `check()` every 2 seconds and prints the current `app.config['count']` to stdout. There's also a button that will spawn a process and add one to the global count -- when checked from inside the same function, it works correctly, but when `check()` tries, it's always stuck at 0.

Does anyone know what's wrong here? The sleep in `do_adding_stuff()` is just a placeholder for other stuff I'll be doing before adding to the count.

```
from flask import Flask, redirect, url_for
from time import sleep
from multiprocessing import Process

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['count'] = 0

def do_adding_stuff():
    sleep(4)

    print 'previous count: ' + str(app.config['count'])
    app.config['count'] =+ 1
    print 'new count: ' + str(app.config['count'])


@app.route('/')
def index():
    return """
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
var a = setInterval(function(){
    $.post("/check", {"dummy": "data"})
}, 2000)
</script>
<form method="post" action="add">
<input type="submit" value="add 1 to count">
</form>
"""

@app.route('/add', methods=['POST'])
def add():
    proc = Process(target=do_adding_stuff)
    proc.start()

    return redirect(url_for('index'))

@app.route('/check', methods=['POST'])
def check():
    print('check(): ' + str(app.config['count']))
    return ''

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

And output:

```
check(): 0
check(): 0
check(): 0
check(): 0
previous count: 0
new count: 1
check(): 0
check(): 0
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're using separate processes. There is no such thing as a global variable when you do that.

Switch to threads (warning: the Python interpreter lock makes threading fairly inefficient) or use a multiprocessing.Value: see http://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html for details.

Note: you need to protect updating that Value with a Lock. Otherwise you'll lose some updates.